# How does the sandwich argument for sequence convergence work?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

I'm taking a course in probability and the professor is talking about convergence. He said:

If $|a_i - a |  \leq b_i$, for all $i$, and $b_i \to 0$, then $a_i \to a$.

He said there is a sandwich argument which says if we have one number that converges to some number A and another sequence which converges to that same number A and our sequence is somewhere in between, then our sequence must also converge to that particular number A.

I'm still not understanding it, especially the formula.

Comment: I'm new to this realm of stackexchange. Please let me know if I'm breaking posting guidelines or where I can find instructions for proper posts.

Comment: It's not really probability, more like calculus: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem

Answer (score 0):

Since $0 \leq |a_i - a |\leq b_i$ then taking limits we have $0 \leq \lim_{i\to\infty} |a_i - a |\leq 0$ so the limit in the middle must also be zero and we can conclude that $a_i \to a$